# how to install noMachine from remote ssh

Tags: remote-desktop, nomachine-nx, nomachine

How to install noMachine from remote SSH client, i already have sudo access.
I have only SSH access with root to my ubuntu machine , I am looking for GUI access through noMachine access.
any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Nomachine doesn't make this as easy as it could be.
If you are running nomachine workstation on linux (which allows up to 4 remote desktop sessions; paid software), you can download the package like this (for .deb distributions)

```
wget --content-disposition www.nomachine.com/W/Linux/64/deb
```

This will default to the latest release.

you can then install it from a remote ssh.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply follow the instructions through the computer in front of you, at the [NoMachine download page](https://www.nomachine.com/download) (you will get to the instructions only at the final download page, so keep clicking download (against the version you must download). At the final download nomachine will start downloading on your computer. At this point go to the ongoing download, right-click and copy the download link. Next in your live ssh session download via wget. Type `wget <thecopieddownloadlink>`. You can then follow install instructions and implement them via ssh. Once installation is complete join via the nomachine client. (restart the remote computer in case for some reason nomachine failed to start; normally it starts automatically after install).